# dropbox-api hide display name

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am using Dropbox API in .NET. I was able to create a sharing link using the code below.

```
using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("some_token_here"))
{
  var folderPath = "/test-hide-owner-onsharing";
  var share = await dbx.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(folderPath);
  return share.Url;
}
```

Is there a way to hide the display name in the public dropbox link? I wanted to hide "from John Doe" when some people views the link. Please see attached screenshot. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I have implemented it on my end and it doesn't shows me the owner name

Comment: Found out it depends on the dropbox account type.

Comment: thats great. I spent more than couple of hour to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Found out it depends on the dropbox account type.